# go - creating the substring start to end

Tags: go

I have a string.

```
s = "This is a super dog. This dog is very nice. He play with other dogs. He love to eat."
```

substring() function in golang takes string and the substring string.  But, what if I want to specify the start and end string for my substring?

For example, in this string s, I want the substring to be started from "super" and it should end on "love". so my substring should be,

```
substring = "super dog. This dog is very nice. He play with other dogs. He love"
```

I didnt see the golang provide any of such functionality. Please let me know if there is way we can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
start := strings.Index(s, "super")
end := strings.Index(s[start:], "love")
fmt.Println(s[start:end] + "love") // s[start:end+len("love")] performs better
```

See [here](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Index) for details and more similar methods.